# Get "hidden" information in plot() and summary()

Tags: r, hidden

I am using the ABC package in R which computes several statistics that can be plotted. Using
plot( the results as matrix from another function in the package ) or
summary( the results as matrix from another function in the package )
several plots/statistics are displayed.
I am interested to get the maximum value of one of the graphs that is displayed. However, the values of the plotted graphs are not returned or used in the input matrix.
How can I get them, or how can I see what function was applied to construct the graph?

Comment: Could you provide an example with data?

Comment: Are you sure they're not being returned invisibly?  Try `str(x <- summary(foo))` and/or `str(y <- plot(foo))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, to view the code for S3 methods, you would type the generic method, followed by a dot. followed by the S3 class.  For example, to view the code dispatched on a `glm` object by the method `summary`:

```
summary.glm
```

Same rule applies for the `abc` package, however it seems that the authors have not exported their methods into the namespace.  Thus, you have to specify the `abc` package namespace.  Try:

```
abc:::summary.abc
abc:::plot.abc
abc:::hist.abc
```

for summary(), plot(), hist(), respectively.

As Joshua notes, the str() function is helpful to view how data is stored in an object.  For example, after running `example(abc)` to generate the examples from the `abc` vignette, the object `lin2` is produced, which is of class `abc`.  Trying `str(lin2)` shows how the data is stored.  Then if you wanted to see the adjusted values for `lin2`, you could try `lin2$adj.values`.